# Creating a Crystal Report using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getfillingdata]
    (@itid int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        memo.fullname, memo.company, memo.department, memo.MRnum, 
        memo.date, memo.returndate, memo.remarks, memo.issuedby, 
        item.Itemnumber, item.description, item.qty, item.unitofmeasure
    FROM   
        memo 
    INNER JOIN 
        item ON memo.memID = item.itid
END
GO
```

Yes it shows my data, but each item got separated and creating a new form.

I want to bind my two tables, the `memo` table should bind to the `item` table so it will show the right content of what I want to print.

[here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pyr5.jpg) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXqMO.jpg)

I hope you have patience to teach me , thank you

Comment: can you show an image for the output, your description is a bit confusing 'yes it show my data , but each item got separated and creating a new form. i want to bind my two tables '

Comment: you can use this post as a learning curve [http://dotnetmentors.com/reporting/crystal-report-with-stored-procedure-parameter-and-visual-studio.aspx]

Comment: @JCBorlagdan, i already insert the picture that shows my output , but the image seems to be error and can't view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about what you're trying to achieve however it looks like you need to add grouping to your report.

Perhaps initially take the stored proc out of the equation and just try it with the SQL... does that resolve the issue?

If not, I'd suggest adding a group to your crystal report around the table of items by grouping on memo.memID.

Here's a video that should help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tB7o_H1eE-I